# `runcmd` not executed in cloud-init script when starting up an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I'd like to create 2 users and change a route53 record when an EC2 instance starts up.

After reading [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) and [this document](https://repost.aws/zh-Hant/knowledge-center/ec2-user-account-cloud-init-user-data), I write the following content to its *user data* section.

```
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [users-groups, always]
- [runcmd, always]
users:
- name: brian.lee
  ssh-authorized-keys:
  - ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZ...
    brian.lee@3H1-01-987654.my-company.com
  groups:
  - wheel
  sudo:
  - ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
  shell: /bin/bash
- name: test.user
  ssh-authorized-keys:
  - ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3Nz...
    test.user@3H1-01-12345.my-company.com
  groups:
  - wheel
  sudo:
  - ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
  shell: /bin/bash

runcmd:
- echo aaa > /tmp/test.txt
- |
  export public_ip=$(/usr/bin/curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com)
  sudo sed -i "s|PUBLIC_IP|$public_ip|" /tmp/change_dns.json
- aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id B4QMKZ7DTDEZL1 --change-batch\
  file:///tmp/change_dns.json
write_files:
- path: /tmp/change_dns.json
  owner: root:root
  permissions: '0644'
  content: |-
    {
      "Comment": "redirect route53 record to this EC2",
      "Changes": [
        {
          "Action": "UPSERT",
          "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "bastion.my-company.com",
            "Type": "A",
            "TTL": 300,
            "ResourceRecords": [
              {
                "Value": "PUBLIC_IP"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

The users are created successfully, and the `/tmp/change_dns.json` file is also created without problem.

But `runcmd` section doesn't get executed at all. I can't even find `/tmp/test.txt` in the EC2 instance.

I've checked `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file. But I can't find any error related to `runcmd`.

I've given an IAM role to the EC2 instance so that it has permission to change route53 records.

Does anyone know why `runcmd` doesn't get executed in my cloud-init script?

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html#yaml-examples:%7E:text=%23%20Note%3A%20Don%27t%20write,clean%20LP%3A%20%231707222.) of cloudinit

> Note: Don't write files to /tmp from cloud-init use /run/somedir instead.
> Early boot environments can race systemd-tmpfiles-clean LP: #1707222.

Try change the output file to be elsewhere of /tmp; That complies with what you said there are no errors in the cloudinit logs.

The `runcmd` step should be run in the config stage not the final stage, [as per the doc](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanation/boot.html#:%7E:text=Config%23,including%20runcmd.)

You are putting `runcmd` in the **cloud_final_modules** and expecting it to be run at the end of the process after the `change_dns.json` is created, which is not the case; So, you might need to flip `runcmd` and `writefiles` steps, and run the `writefiles` first, so the json file is ready for the `runcmd` step.